# IOS music api for volume control

Tags: iphone, ios

I'm relatively new to IOS development and have been searching for sound apis. I specifically want to create an app that is able to change the volume of music playing from the itunes app. Is this possible? What are some libraries that achieve this functionality?

Comment: If my answer helped, would you mind checking the arrow next to it so the question will be marked as answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible.  Features like that belong to the operating system, and as such cannot be adjusted in your app.

An important concept in iOS development is that of the sandbox.  Essentially your app lives in its own sandbox, where it cannot adjust other apps or the basic settings of the phone.  This is so for several reasons; none the least of which being security.  If my app could modify the code/see whats going on/what is saved in your app, there is a much larger potential for compromising apps.